# Windows cluster has lost or discarded the CLUSDB

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, cluster, failovercluster

Both nodes of a two node windows failover cluster on 2008R2 have lost the CLUSDB file.
I think this happened because an inexperienced admin came to a cluster with a reserved disk issue and re-installed the Clustering feature over the top of itself.

So there is no config info on the server, no CLUSDB file which means no Registry Hive for the Cluster. On either server. However, the server still knows its part of a cluster. You can't start the cluster service on either side, because the cluster config is missing.
From the cluster.log file

```
[CS] Service CreateNodeThread Failed, ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND(2)' because of 'Open parameters key failed.'
```

There are no backups of the CLUSDB file, its a test cluster so someone saw fit to omit it from backup.

Because I can't start the cluster service, I can't evict the nodes from the cluster, so reconfiguring from scratch isn't going to work.

The last resort as I saw it was uninstall the Clustering feature, but you can't do this whilst a server still thinks it belongs in a cluster.

So the question. Is this a rebuild from scratch including O/S or are there any ways round this?

Answer (score 0):

Restore clusdb file from other cluster node and then start cluster service.

First stop cluster service on active node. Copy clustdb file from C:\Windows\cluster folder and copy on passive node. Start cluster services on passive node and then on active node.

Comment: You missed the very first sentence where I stated that both nodes have lost the clusdb and then went on to describe how...